# Does 'Founded ,the club' mean 'The club,which was founded'?

Tags: relative-clauses, past-participles

"**The club, which was founded 20 years ago**, is more popular today than ever before."

If I express the above relative clause using past participle, which one is correct?

1. *The club ,founded 20 years ago*,  is more popular.. or
2. *Founded 20 years ago, the club* is more popular..?

Comment: They're both fine. It's just a stylistic choice to put the relative clause *before* the noun in #2. But be careful of doing this with longer and more complex constructions, since you're making the reader work harder to understand things if you say something *about* the club before the reader even knows you're talking about a club in the first place.

Comment: Could you tell me how the phrase like my second example is called in English?(a grammar name)

Comment: I'd call #2 a "displaced relative clause", since it would "naturally" occur *after* the noun *(the club)* which it references. But I've no idea what a grammarian would call it.

Comment: I'd say usage of each is dependant on what precedes it. If the entire piece is about the club, the second option would be perfect, emphasising a new point; its age. If the subject of the club was only recently introduced, the first form would be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

All the three sentences are correct and have the same meaning, but with different grammatical constructions.

The first sentence has a non-defining relative clause "which was founded 20 years ago".

The second sentence and the third sentence each has a participle clause/phrase that is a bit like a relative clause. These clauses/phrases are usually used in written English. "Founded 20 years ago" is the participle phrase that modifies or refers to the club.

Comment: Just to be clear. Are you saying that if there's a relative pronoun *(which, who, that, etc.)* then *"founded 20 years ago"* is a "non-defining relative clause", but if no such relative pronoun is present, it becomes a "participle clause"? How would that play out if I recast [*Elephants, which are large and grey, can sometimes be found in zoos.*](http://www.englishlanguageguide.com/grammar/non-defining-relative-clause.asp) to *Large and grey, elephants can sometimes be found in zoos* ?

Comment: FumbleFingers, there is a relative pronoun and an auxiliary in the relative clause, whereas participle clauses can be formed without them. A participle clause must have a present or past participle. Sir, it's missing in your example (Large and grey).